# Solve for X and Y

Tags: problem-solving

I have the following equation:

$0 = 34x^2+92xy+68y^2−250x−344y+461$

I cannot find any way to get the values of both x and y from this equation, any help would be much appreciated, especially a step by step solution.

Edit: I'm quite new to this site, if there's any way for me to improve this question please edit it or let me know!

Comment: One way to improve the post would be to present your work. Also, what do we know about $x$ and $y$? Complex, real, integer...? This equation surely has a continuum of complex roots. You can view it as a quadratic equation in $x$ and solve in terms of $y$ as a parameter.

Comment: They are all real numbers. Would a quadratic equation work with 10 or more variables?

Comment: You are changing your post in the wrong direction. Without showing any of your own efforts, you should definitely not ask for a step-by-step solution. As they say in shark tank, "I'm out".

Comment: Of course, my apologies. I'll keep the question the same and open another one if necessary. Let's focus on just two variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving for $x$ with the usual formula,

$$x=\frac{-(92y-250)\pm\sqrt{(92y-250)^2-4\cdot34\cdot(68y^2-344y+461)}}{68}.$$

After simplification, the discriminant is

$$-196(2y-1)^2,$$ which is only non-negative when $$y=\frac12.$$

$x$ follows.

Comment: Great answer! What is the formula you used to do this?

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld: as said in the comments.

Comment: As far as I know, the quadratic formula is: x = (-b ± √(b²-4ac))/2a, however what you have used doesn't seem to be the same

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld: it is exactly that one. What differences do you see ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm not sure where you got the values of a b and c from for the formula, I thought a=34 (from 34x^2), b=-250 (from -250x) and c=461 (from +461)

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld: no, these are not the coefficients of $x^2, x$ and the constant term ?

Answer (score 0):

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 23 }{ 17 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 125 }{ 34 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
34 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 98 }{ 17 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 23 }{ 17 }  &  -  \frac{ 125 }{ 34 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
34 & 46 &  - 125 \\ 
46 & 68 &  - 172 \\ 
 - 125 &  - 172 & 461 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

So 
$$  x +  \frac{ 23 }{ 17 } y    -  \frac{ 125 }{ 34 } = 0  $$
$$  y   -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } = 0 $$
because 34 times the square of the first one plus $ \frac{ 98 }{ 17 }$ times the square of the second must be zero.

The relationship between the matrices $D,H$ is called congruence